# Reading stdin with read()

Tags: c, stdin

I am trying to read input from stdin; however, as a result, I don't receive anything, even with the checking for '\n'.Please, give some hints.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define READLINE_READ_SIZE 10

char * my_readline(int fd)
{
char *buffer=malloc(READLINE_READ_SIZE+1);
int i=0;
int size;
char ch;
for(;(size=read(fd,&ch,1))==1;i++)
{
    if(i==READLINE_READ_SIZE||ch=='\n')
    break;
    else{
        buffer[i]=ch;
    }
}
buffer[i]='\0';
return buffer;
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    char *arr=malloc(READLINE_READ_SIZE+1);
    arr=my_readline(0);
    printf("%s",arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I didn't check througougly, bour code looks more or less OK. What __exactly__ are you typing? Here it works fine when I type e.g. `1` `2` `3` `Enter`

Comment: BTW (not actually related to your problem), but the malloc part here `char *arr=malloc(READLINE_READ_SIZE+1);` is totally useless and it doesn't make any sense. Exercise for you: explain why.

Comment: Note that reading 1 character at a time with `read` is pretty inefficient, since you're doing a `read` system call for each and every character you read.

Comment: `char *arr=malloc(READLINE_READ_SIZE+1);` - The allocation here is redundant as you later assign the address `buffer` contains to `arg` and with that point to the memory allocated inside `my_readline()`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky and it's a memory leak, although in this case it's exiting shortly after so makes little difference.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the response. 1. For example, my input is ./a.out Hello, but it doesn't print me it. 2. Yes, I agree with you; however, my function must return char*.

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 "*however, my function must return `char*`*". - You did not understand where Jabberwocky and me pointed you at. Read it twice.

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 The point is that you should delete the `malloc` call from `main`.  You don't need to change `my_readline` to fix your `malloc` bug.  The assignment in `main` is dead (aside from the memory leak) and makes no sense.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio yep, no outputs. My input is a basic string, nothing more.

Comment: @TomKarzes but in this case, if I delete my malloc from main, how I am gonna free the allocated memory?

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 I have to ask: Do you press to Enter? Also, Do you know if the program is finished and it showed no output or it might stuck somewhere?

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 The `free()` call deallocates the memory allocated inside `my_readline()`. It does not affect the memory allocated in `main()`.

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 You're already freeing the memory allocated by `my_readline`.  That's what your `free` call is doing.  You're *not* freeing the memory allocated in `main`, since you're discarding the address before freeing it, and you're not using it in any way.  You have a memory leak.  Deleting the `malloc` call from `main` will fix it.

Comment: @Nurdaulet_mit22 Look at it this way:  What value do you think `arr` has when you call `free`?  Is it the value returned by the `malloc` call in `main`?  Or is it the value returned by `my_readline`?  Answer:  It has the value given to it in the last assignment.  That's the value returned by `my_readline`.  You have lost the value returned by the `malloc` call in `main`.  It's a bug.

Comment: @TomKarzes ooooh, I think I got it! Thanks!